# How can I access the default webdriver for Selenium 2 with Rails 3 Rspec and Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to implement Selenium webdriver for a couple days to do my javascript testing. I have installed and included the gem `selenium-webdriver` in my `Gemfile`. A few simple tests pass by adding `, js: true` to an Rspec test.

Nothing else was necessary: When the tests are run, a Firefox window opens the current page specified earlier in the file with Capybara `visit path("/news/#{news_item.id}")` and then a button is clicked, displaying a form that was hidden, fields are filled, and a submit button is pressed, no problem. The test passes and the browser closes.

Advancing to more complex tests require me to call methods on the webdriver, but I don't know how to access it, because I did not explicitly create one. I could, however, if I wanted create my own with `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox` but this causes a second browser instance to open, and it is completely blank rather than opening the page Capybara navigated to.

My question is:
How can I get access to the default webdriver being used so that I can call methods such as `empty_stars = driver.find_element(:class, "empty-stars-container")` and `driver.action.move_to(empty_stars).perform` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get access to the webdriver in Capybara using:

```
page.driver.browser
```

So you would want to do something like:

```
empty_stars = page.driver.browser.find_element(:class, "empty-stars-container")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can now access the default webdriver and call methods on it no problem.